# Extracting first 3 elements from list of strings in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract the first 3 elements from a list of strings from the `'1/1'` column.
My `df_unique` looks like that:

```
                                                                                    1/1                                                             0/0  count
0              ['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25', 'P1-26', 'P1-28', 'P1-6', 'P1-88', 'P1-93']                            ['P1-89', 'P1-90', 'P1-92', 'P1-95']      1
1              ['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25', 'P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-89', 'P1-92', 'P1-95']                                     ['P1-28', 'P1-90', 'P1-93']      1
2    ['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25', 'P1-26', 'P1-88', 'P1-89', 'P1-92', 'P1-93', 'P1-95']                                      ['P1-28', 'P1-6', 'P1-90']      1
3             ['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25', 'P1-26', 'P1-88', 'P1-89', 'P1-92', 'P1-93']                                      ['P1-28', 'P1-6', 'P1-90']      1
```

I've tried to use different solutions:

```
df_extract_3 = df_unique['1/1'].str.split().map(lambda lst: [string[0:3] for string in lst])
```

but the result looks like that:

```
0           [['P, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1]
1           [['P, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1]
2      [['P, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1]
3           [['P, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1, 'P1]
```

And the second solution:

```
df_extract_3 = df_unique['1/1'].str[0:3]
```

gives:

```
0      ['P
1      ['P
2      ['P
3      ['P
```

When I try to add `split` :

```
df_extract_3 = df_unique['1/1'].str.split().str[0:3]
```

the final result is:

```
0      [['P1-12',, 'P1-22',, 'P1-25',]
1      [['P1-12',, 'P1-22',, 'P1-25',]
2      [['P1-12',, 'P1-22',, 'P1-25',]
3      [['P1-12',, 'P1-22',, 'P1-25',]
```

What should I change to receive 'normal' output like:

```
0      ['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25']
1      ['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25']
2      ['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25']
3      ['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25']
```

? I know it can be easy modification but I've stuck and messed with that...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert your strings to read lists, then slice with [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html):

```
import ast
df_unique['1/1'] = df_unique['1/1'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df_unique['0/0'] = df_unique['0/0'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df_extract_3 = df_unique['1/1'].str[:3]
print(df_extract_3)
```

Or in one shot:

```
df_extract_3 = df_unique['1/1'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)[:3])
```

Output:

```
0    [P1-12, P1-22, P1-25]
1    [P1-12, P1-22, P1-25]
2    [P1-12, P1-22, P1-25]
3    [P1-12, P1-22, P1-25]
Name: 1/1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great, that works perfectly, thanks @mozway! Is it possible the datatype of column ```1/1``` was "messed up" after conversion from one string like 'P1-25, P1-12, P1-22' to a list of strings with ```str.split(',')```?

Comment: Likely the other way around, it could have been a normal list and converted to string representation of list with `astype(str)` or similar.

Comment: Ok, I've found that moment in my previous code lines, thanks!

Comment: After using your code I cannot run the following lines with ```groupby``` function for the newly extracted data and it raises me ```TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'```. So how can I change it now, @mozway, to be able to use ```groupby``` for that?

Comment: If you refer to the `df_unique['1/1'] = df_unique['1/1'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` run `df_unique['1/1'] = df_unique['1/1'].astype(str)`. That said, using a string representation might not be ideal, you can also try: `df_unique['1/1'] = df_unique['1/1'].apply(tuple)` (from the lists). To have a container **and** being able to group, you can also use tuples: `df_extract_3 = df_unique['1/1'].apply(lambda x: tuple(ast.literal_eval(x)[:3]))`. Experiment with it and open a new question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
data={"1/1":[['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25', 'P1-26', 'P1-28', 'P1-6', 'P1-88', 'P1-93'],
        ['P1-12', 'P1-22', 'P1-25', 'P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-89', 'P1-92', 'P1-95']],
"0/0":[1,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df["1/1"]=df["1/1"].apply(lambda x:x[0:3])
```

```
print(df)
                     1/1    0/0
0   [P1-12, P1-22, P1-25]   1
1   [P1-12, P1-22, P1-25]   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
df_unique['1/1'] = [element[:3] for element in df_unique['1/1']]
```